# Width on mega menu dropdown

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I had a menubar there was taking a whole row:
Before image of the website.

I wanted the menubar to be between the logo and the shopping-cart. I solved that with doing the following:

I added this CSS:

```
header .container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
    .navbar-header { width:100%} 
}
```

and changed the original sequence in the html code from:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
if(th_is_woocommerce_activated()) // Shopping cart
<nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
```

to

```
<div class="navbar-header">
<nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
if(th_is_woocommerce_activated()) // Shopping cart
```

This partly solved the problem. But the Mega menu is extremly small on both desktop and mobile view now. The website is here:

I would like the dropmenu is getting the same width as on the picture. But I cannot figure out where to set the width?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that because you set display to flex and because the width of the dropdown is relative to the parent, it's not going to be easy to set its width to the width of the entire menu.

If I apply the style

```
.mega-sub-menu {
   width: 1200px;
   position: absolute;
   left: -200px;
}
```

I get this...
[image]

Which is problematic for multiple reasons.

This menu would be very simple to rebuild through the ftp with flex-box.  I would do that or try using a different plugin.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I just tried to add your code, but I do not get any change? I dont think I have the talents at the moment to make it with a flexbox. I would like to learn, but I have a customer who is pushing to get the menu on the right spot asap.

Comment: Understandable.  The code I gave you is unresponsive anyway.  Plus, I doubt your client would be thrilled about their logo and the cart getting cut off.

Comment: Agree John, he would be quite angry with this :-) To be honest I actually did not know It would be hard to solve. I should have looked into the flexbox from the start. But he also would like edit the menu, and he cannot code. So therefore I need a plugin for it.

Comment: Can I show you how it is looking like from the start, before I made the flexbox? Maybe you have a suggestion from there.

Comment: Of course! I would recommend maybe finding another menu plugin.  That might be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `display:flex` added to the `header .container` is causing this situation.
To solve this, you should remove the flex style and place the logo and shopping cart in absolute position.

```
.container>.navbar-header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 160px;
}
.container>.navbar-collapse {
    margin-top: 85px;
    margin-left: 75px;
}
.themo_cart_icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 160px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the suggestion @Hareesh. I just tried to add your code to the page. The menu is looking good now, but the logo, menu and shopping cart is jumping totally around with this solution?

Comment: This solution is also not responsive? I can see the menu is centered behind the logo on mobile view.

Comment: You'll have to add the necessary styles for viewing in the mobile screens.

Comment: @MK-DK can you please elaborate a little? I'm not sure I understand what exactly the issue is.

Comment: Yes ok sure. I would like the Logo, menu and cart on a nice straight line. Exact how @John Sims picture is. But the solution also have to be responsive. I added your code, but the logo, menu and Cart is not aligned straight.

Comment: It is fine in my screen here. In case it is not in a straight line, adjusting the `top`, `left` and `right` values for the logo and cart will fix it.

Comment: I have a feeling that this is a very bad solution. So I am placing it so it is looking good on my screen, but on yours it is messed up. Then I can keep hardcore this. Dosent feel right. Thanks for the suggestion though.